# Handling with the 'error' parameter inside a callback function in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

I have multiple controllers and every controller has this error handler:

```
if (error) {
  res.render('error', {
     error: error
  });
}
```

Sometimes I have more than one:

```
exports.update = function(req, res, next) {
    MyModel.findById(req.params.id, function(error, event) {
        if (error) {
            res.render('error', {
                error: error
            });
        }
        else {
            event['active'] === false ? event['active'] = true : event['active'] = false;

            event.update({
                'active': event['active']
            }, function(error) {
                if (error) {
                    res.render('error', {
                        error: error
                    });
                }
                else {
                    res.end('Success!');
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
```

I have more than 30 controllers and this seems like an inefficient way of handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of your functions adhere to this pattern you can wrap them in,
you guessed it, another function:

```
defaultError = function(handler) {
    return function(error) {
        if (error) {
            res.render('error', {
                error: error
            });
        }
        else {
            return handler.apply(null, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        }
    };
};
```

This uses the
[special `arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments),
which has to be converted to an array before you can `slice` off the `error` object, and `apply` on the passed-in function.

Now the previously repetitive code gets a bit shorter:

```
exports.update = function(req, res, next) {
    MyModel.findById(req.params.id, defaultError(function(event) {
        event['active'] === false ? event['active'] = true : event['active'] = false;

        event.update({
            'active': event['active']
        }, defaultError(function() {
            res.end('Success!');
        }));
    }));
};
```

Now obviously the `defaultError` can also customize the rendered error,
so as long as `error` is in a fixed position in the call, this pattern
can be used to build a small control flow abstraction.

The cost here is a possible speed penalty due to the manipulation of `arguments` and the `apply` call.

If you had promises a generic error handler would be equally
viable, but it looks like that is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to promisify your code using one of promise libs like Kris koval's Q or Bluebird and use default error handling function in catch block.

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to Code Review!  We tend to favor longer answers that include examples of the code changes that you are proposing as well as explanations of *why* the changes are improvements.